# Caching Google Maps android?

Tags: android, google-maps, caching

I am working on this app which users may or may not have GPRS OR WiFI connection. So when the user types in a source and a destination, I want to cache the maps needed in a city level view (Zoom 12). Is there an way to accomplish this task? I saw that Google Map API references to a caching feature however I couldn't find any code for it.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MapView widget for Android, at present (August 2012), does not support any outside control over caching or client persistence.

Comment: Please share the reference?